# Compiling the source code in java 1.6.0

Tags: java, version

teacher said: "your source code should compile in java “1.6.0”. This version is general. I search but cannot find the version.

Which version you think is better in this situation from following site:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

**How can we understand witch version of this site is almost the same version that we want**

Comment: Please be more specific and try to say what features will be required or provide a sample of the code, otherwise the most recent version of java and the link you provided should be okay for learning purposes.

Comment: Why does your teacher say that?  If you are doing real Java(tm) programming, you should be using Java 7, and look to move on to Java 8 when it is released.  Java 6 has been "end-of-lifed" ... and that means no more security patches.

Answer (score 1):

[JDK 1.6 update 45](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR) is the latest version for Java 6, so use that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to have exact version. Most of the code you write can be compiled in other version if you are just starting java programming, based on your question it seems you are just beginning.

There won't be too many changes among different updates of one version. So, you don't have to worry about it. If you want to be sure what ever you write can be compiled in 1.6.0, you can take any version of 1.5 and develop your code. This way your code will almost always compile in any version of 1.6. So, go ahead and use Java SE Development Kit 6u45.

Or if you want to just run already compiled code, it is enough if you take latest version of JRE.

Answer (score 0):

When someone says *'your source code should compile in java “1.6.0”'* they mean *any* Java 1.6.0 distribution.

All of the downloads on that page are for Java 1.6.0, so anyone of them will do.  But with Java it is best to use the most recent patch release.  This is currently Java 1.6.0 patch 45.

---

For the record, you are pretty much *guaranteed* that if your code will compile with one patch release of Java 1.6.0, it will compile with all of the.  (As in, I am not aware of *any* case where this won't be true ... modulo the possibility of obscure compiler bugs in earlier patch releases.)